# Query within date range for specific data

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

I have an index of events like so (please excuse the simplified free hand version)

```
{event:{ properties: {id:{type: 'string'}, start:{type: 'date'}}}
```

I want to query this data to return all events within a week from now, with an additional weekend filter. I accomplish the first part of the query with the following.

```
{
"query": {
"range": {
  "start": {
    "from": "2014-02-25 09:14:09 UTC",
    "to": "2014-03-04 09:14:09 UTC"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

but I have a problem I want to query the week as above, but I only need five of the days from the result set, if a weekend falls within the five days and has an event then return that event f not return a further day so in essence

### with no weekend event should look like this

wed, thurs, fri, mon, tues

### with weekendd event should look like this

wed, thurs, fri, sat, mon

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the requirement instead, I ma not totally sure this is possible in elastic search, so I have took the seven days and used code to filter the results